# opencv_traincascade train classifier using GPU

Tags: gpu, opencv3.0, cascade-classifier

I have try to train my classifier using opencv_traincascade in my machine. When run it, it utilize 100% of my CPU but not use my GPU. I have install OpenCV 3.x in my Ubuntu 16.04. And I have GeForece GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2. I success install the driver with CUDA 8.0. How I can use the GPU instead of using CPU? I use below script to train the module in

opnencv_traincascade -data data -vec positives.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 37000 -numNeg 756 -numStage 20 -w 20 -h 20

Any configuration I need to set to use the GPU?

Answer (score 1):

To use OpenCV with multi-threading and CUDA, you need to build an OpenCV as in this [guide](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/buildcompile-opencv-v3-3-on-windows-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/)

Or you can [download](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/downloads/) an already assembled OpenCV by first installing all the necessary components (CUDA Toolkit, TBB, MKL) and setting the environment variables in Path

Comment: Very useful guide.